# Solving an ODE - exact one?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ODE,

> $$y' \arcsin(y)-x\sqrt{1-y^2} \arcsin ^2 (y) = 2x\sqrt{1-y^2}. $$

I guess that using some algebraic manipulations, I need to transform the equation into something in which I will be able to use the fact that $(\arcsin (x) ) ' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, but didn't manage to understand how exactly. I did manage to obtain the following form, in which I cannot see how to integrate the LHS,
$$
\frac{\arcsin(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2+\arcsin ^2 (y) } dy = x dx.
$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you are, just integrate both sides.  On the LHS,  using the u substitution $u=\arcsin(y)$,  you get $\frac u {2 + u^2}$ which integrates nice and simply to $\frac 1 2 \ln (2+u)$,  so that brings the whole thing to
$$\frac 1 2 \ln (2+\arcsin y)=\frac 1 2 x^2+C$$
Canceling the 1/2 and bring up both sides to the $e$ gets us to

$$2+\arcsin(y)=e^{x^2+C}$$
Subtract 2 then take $\sin$ of both sides to get
$$y=\sin(e^{x^2+C}-2)=\sin(C'e^{x^2}-2)$$ where $C'>0$

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.John No problem,  you were almost there in the setup and identifying the $u$ substitution, just needed to do it!

Comment: @Alan doesn't $\frac{u}{u^2+2}$ integrate to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(u^2+2)$

Comment: With an integration to a logarithm, you lose the sign of the expression inside (via the absolute value), so that in reversing that expression any sign is possible, which means that $C'$ can also be negative or zero.